# Why I can add folder to `On My iPad` location but I cannot add folder to `On My iPhone` location?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, files.app

On my iPad I can create folders wherever I'm in, but on my iPhone I cannot create folder in the location `On My iPhone` but I can create folders in side the apps' folders like `Acrobat`.

iPadOS: 14.2 and iOS: 12.4.8

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new feature of iOS 13.

Your iPad is on iPadOS 14.2 so has the feature and your iPhone is on iOS 12.4.8 so does not have the feature.